# Using a for loop to call a character method multiple times. The for loop will then convert each character to a string

Tags: java

The output should look like the attached screenshot. I am stuck on the very last step. Using a for loop to call the getCharacter method 10 times and converting the characters to a string using the Character.toString() method. [image]

``
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
   int count = countNumbers();
  
   countPlay(count);
   
   String word = getCharacter();
   
   stringOf10(word);
   
   
}
public static double getRealNumber(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a real number, one that has a decimal point: ");
    double realNumber = sc.nextDouble();
    return realNumber;
}
public static int countNumbers(){
    int count = 0;
    do{
      if (getRealNumber() == -1.0)
            break;
      count++;
      } while(true);   
    System.out.println("The count is " + count);
    return count;
}
public static int countPlay(int count){
    int exponent = 4;
    double result = 0;
    result = Math.pow(count, exponent);
    System.out.println(count + "^" + exponent + " is " + result );
    return count;
}
public static char getCharacter(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("You will be asked to enter 10 characters.");
    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    char character = input.next().charAt(0);
    return character;
}
public static char stringOf10(String word){
    char i = getCharacter();
    i = Character.toString(word) ;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    }
    return word;
}
```

}

``

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 10;` does not iterate 10 times. It iterates eleven times.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it, but right now it actually does not iterate at all.

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but have you considered _not_ having everything static?  My instinct with a question like this is to have a class where a `String` field stores the characters you've accumulated so far, and a method that adds a character onto it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I actually didn't not know you could do that. If you can't tell I am very new to java and coding. I think its supposed to be static for now.

Comment: I suppose you could use a static String within the class.  In other words, declare a variable like `private static String accumulatedWord = "";` outside of all the class's methods.  It's not ideal but it will get you over the line if you haven't learnt about objects yet.

Comment: This loop `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    }` is not doing anything

Comment: @ScaryWombat I know that's the entire reason I am here. My for loop does nothing and I have no idea what to put inside it to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following block of code which will run in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = "";
    //Print the instructions before the loop
    System.out.println("You will be asked to enter 10 characters.");
    //request characters inside the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        word += input.next().charAt(0);
    }
    //print the result (or return from a method)
    System.out.println("The word is: " + word);
    //return word;
}
```

Besides the corrections in comments, note how we create a local variable `word`, and simply update/append that inside the `for` loop `word += input.next().charAt(0);`.

You can easily move this code to fit your needs and return the value to be printed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Call the method to get our word and save the result
    String result = stringOf10();
    //Print the result
    System.out.println("The word is: " + result);
}

public static String stringOf10(){
    //Creater a scanner once before the loop
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Create a local variable to store the word as it is updated
    String word = "";
    //Print the instructions once before the loop
    System.out.println("You will be asked to enter 10 characters.");

    //Create a loop that will run 10 times "for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)"
    //The loop starts by creating an int that is 0 "int i=0"
    //Each time the loop ends it will do "i = i+1"
    //The loop will run until i is no longer less than 10 "i < 10"
    //Once that happens the loop will end and the code after the loop will run
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //Dach time the loop will call this method and update the word
        word += getCharacter(input);
    }
    return word;
}

public static char getCharacter(Scanner input){
    //Each time this method is called we prompt the user to enter a character
    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    //We then return the character to the previous method
    return input.next().charAt(0);

}
```

Comment: I have to have a method called stringOf10(); to get credit.

Comment: @Regis See the updated answer returning a string. Or do you need to return one character at a time?

Comment: I have to call my getCharacter method 10 times using the for loop inside of the stringOf10() method. I am sorry for the trouble as this is a solution, but I cannot take input in the stringOf10() method it has to call the method that takes the input and returns the character to be converted to the string.

Comment: @Regis doing that uses the exact same code, just split into another method. Give it a go yourself or see my updated answer.

Comment: that works I still don't totally understand why it works though. I never really understood for loops or strings. I find any other loop to be much easier to use. Is there any chance you could maybe explain as simply as possible exactly how your solution works?

Comment: @Regis For all intents and purposes, a `for` loop is basically the same as a `while(...)` loop, but it simply has a nice and tidy way to specify the length of the conditions of the loop, for example when it should end, rather than relying on additional `if` checks and `int` counters inside the loop. I have updated my answer with comments in the code to help explain what is happening.